# print out the longest string in c

Tags: c

Given any number of program parameters input into the command-line, calculate the length of each one, and lastly output the longest string. Here is my code, but it seems to be wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  size_t maxlen = 0, len;
  int i;
  int longest;


  for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
   len = strlen(argv[i]);
     if (len > maxlen) 
       longest = argv[i];
  }

  printf("The longest string is %s. \n", longest);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Guys, let's not beat on the guy with a bunch of downvotes/closevotes. What he wants to do is clear. He's obviously a beginner, but that's not a crime.

Comment: you have a mistake in the if statement, and you should use `short` instead of char (just for keeping the code readable). can you explain **why** the code seems wrong?

Comment: You should compile with all warnings enabled. I think that `longest` should be declared `char *longest;`, not `int longest;` and the compiler should warn you about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mistakes:

One. `char max; ... max = strlen(argv[i]);` wrong; `strlen()` returns `size_t` and not a `char`.

Two: `if(max < argv[i])` also wrong, you're comparing the length of the string with a pointer to the string. That doesn't even make sense. What you probably want is

```
size_t maxlen = 0, len;
int i, maxindex = 0;

for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    len = strlen(argv[i]);
    if (len > maxlen) {
        maxlen = len;
        maxindex = i;
    }
}

printf("The longest string is '%s'\n", argv[maxindex]);
```

Comment: +1 for doing it the right way, and not just correcting the problem

Comment: I want to output the string as a result, i have update my script. but i think i did something wrong

Comment: @StevenLiu Then you need to keep track of the index of the longest string in the argv array as well, not only its length. See edit.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in here:

```
max = strlen(argv[i]);
if(max < argv[i])
{
  max=argv[i];
}
```

You seem to be a bit confused about what `max` is for here. What you really want to do is:

- take `strlen(argv[i])`, and store it in a variable
- check whether it is greater than `max`
- if it is, store it in `max`

Try translating that to C code and post what you come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean:

```
int i;
int max = strlen(argv[0]);

for (i = 0; i < argc; ++i) 
{
    if (max < strlen(argv[i]))
    {
        max = strlen(argv[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: also, max should probably be an int, not a char (strings can be longer than 255 characters)

Comment: @cegfault it should actually be a `size_t`.

Comment: @H2CO3: yeah, you're right.  But seeing how the OP doesn't seem to have a good understanding of the `char` and `int`, I wouldn't want to confuse him by throwing `size_t` into the mix before he gets the basics down

Comment: @cegfault tanks for the upvote. Two: "doing it the right way" also incorporates using a `size_t` :) If by accident `size_t` is as wide or wider as int, and there's a very long string, then using an int can signed-overflow which is undefined behavior.

Comment: Agreed, but seeing how he is reading command line arguments, if he's reaching a signed overflow I will be more impressed and confused than anything else ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
int max = 0;//assuming  initial max length of 0. start loop from index 1 (index 0 is program name)
for(i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {

    int len = strlen(argv[i]);//get length of str
    if(max < len )
    {
       max=len;//store the new max length
    }
}
```